# Is there any HTML wysiwyg editor?

Tags: asp.net, html, wysiwyg

I wonder whether there is any good WYSIWYG editor when it comes to editing complex HTML pages generated from ASP.NET, PHP, GWT or anything else. I've tried a lot of WYSIWYG tools, but after a certain point I always end up with manually editing the HTML source code or CSS to fix different issues. The editors I've tried are never compatible with the ASP.NET/PHP/etc code I'm writing.

**Edit**: I have used Visual Studio for a few years to do ASP.NET development. After a while, it always comes to the point where I can't even open the pages and user controls because they rely on so many things which aren't available in debug time.

Comment: how about the Visual Studio editor?

Comment: yep @Marek visual studio editor works fine.... just use the split mode and see what you are writing..

Comment: You may as well just stick with editing by hand. I have tried plenty of wysiwyg editors, but like you, end hand codeing more often. Though I do find something like notpad++ is nice when working with lots of code, either PHP or JS

Comment: Added the 'subjective' tag as this kind of question boils down to a question of taste. That's not to say that there will be no useful answers... just lots of conflicting ones :)

Comment: S.Lott, I've tried to Google it but have not found any WYSIWYG editor which works with complex usages.

Answer (score 5):

You're not going to get anything that is perfect. You're almost always going to have to tweak the mark-up by hand at least a little bit.

Your best bet would probably be [Adobe Dreamweaver](http://www.adobe.com/products/dreamweaver/) for PHP and Visual Studio ([Visual Studio Web Developer Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/) is free) for ASP.NET.

Comment: +1 for lowering expectations. :) *Nothing* in the WYSIWYG editor field is perfect, and you will *always* have to know HTML/CSS and be able to tweak.

Answer (score 1):

I love VS, but I'd rather make sweet love to a hedgehog than use the HTML editor. [Expression Web](http://www.microsoft.com/Expression/products/Web_Overview.aspx) does a much better job editing HTML.

Comment: Except in those odd circumstances where it shows it's FrontPage heritage and reformats the html into a non-working state.  Granted, Expression is MUCH better than FrontPage used to be about this.  But some of those issues are still there.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think that Visual Studio is the best for ASP.NET, although Expression Web also seems to be pretty good.

But I personally I think it's the best for you to start writing more code and using the WYSIWYG part less and less. 
With Web applications it's all about the way they're displayed in the browser and I think that the browser is the tool which should be used for testing the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, I have Expression Web right now and it works well.  You can move stuff around in design view but will of course, as stated above, have to render the code manually.  But it works if you wanna see the changes you have made.  I would always of course view it in the browser and not just rely on the design view.  Also [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com) is a great tool.

Answer (score 0):

WYSIWYG editors for complex web site/applications just never measure up ***IMHO***.

The problem comes down to wanting control of the HTML/CSS markup, yet also the flexibility to create a GUI via drag-n-drop. (the 2 are almost polar opposites)

Take a ***very simple*** example.

In WYSIWYG mode, I type/create (pretend that **World** is on the line right after Hello (the Markdown editor forces me to add an extra line break)):

> Hello
>
> **World**

What HTML should the editor create?

```
Hello<br/>
<b>World</b>

<p>Hello</p>
<p><strong>World</strong></p>

<div>Hello</div>
<div><span style="font-weight:bold;">World</span></div>

<span class="abcNormal">Hello</span>
<br/>
<span class="abcBold">World</span>
```

(and a zillion more possibilities)

I still think the best thing you can have is an editor/IDE that understands your component/tags and provides auto-completion and code-assist/intellisense - paired up with a very quick deploy option to test changes ASAP in real browser(s)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at BBCode Editor

http://richtexteditor.com/demo/bbcode.aspx

This example shows a simple BBCode formatter for the Editor.

Answer (score -1):

Try graphical (wysiwyg) HTML editor [NEEDEE](https://needee.net)

**Main features:**

- Drag & drop functionality
- Element resizing, reshaping, cloning & positioning tools
- Almost all HTML5 elements also bootstrap and custom components
- CSS editing tools

[graphical HTML editor](https://needee.net/graphical-html-editor.html)

[NEEDEE workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3Dmd.jpg)